# What is the fastest way to bulk load data into HBase programmatically?

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, hbase

I have a Plain text file with possibly millions of lines which needs custom parsing and I want to load it into an HBase table as fast as possible (using Hadoop or HBase Java client).

My current solution is based on a **MapReduce** job without the Reduce part. I use `FileInputFormat` to read the text file so that each line is passed to the `map` method of my `Mapper` class. At this point the line is parsed to form a `Put` object which is written to the `context`. Then, `TableOutputFormat` takes the `Put` object and inserts it to table.

This solution yields an average insertion rate of 1,000 rows per second, which is less than what I expected. **My HBase setup is in pseudo distributed mode on a single server.**

One interesting thing is that during insertion of 1,000,000 rows, 25 Mappers (tasks) are spawned but they run serially (one after another); is this normal?

Here is the code for my current solution:

```
public static class CustomMap extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, ImmutableBytesWritable, Put> {

    protected void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException {
        Map<String, String> parsedLine = parseLine(value.toString());

        Put row = new Put(Bytes.toBytes(parsedLine.get(keys[1])));
        for (String currentKey : parsedLine.keySet()) {
            row.add(Bytes.toBytes(currentKey),Bytes.toBytes(currentKey),Bytes.toBytes(parsedLine.get(currentKey)));
        }

        try {
            context.write(new ImmutableBytesWritable(Bytes.toBytes(parsedLine.get(keys[1]))), row);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

public int run(String[] args) throws Exception {
    if (args.length != 2) {
        return -1;
    }

    conf.set("hbase.mapred.outputtable", args[1]);

    // I got these conf parameters from a presentation about Bulk Load
    conf.set("hbase.hstore.blockingStoreFiles", "25");
    conf.set("hbase.hregion.memstore.block.multiplier", "8");
    conf.set("hbase.regionserver.handler.count", "30");
    conf.set("hbase.regions.percheckin", "30");
    conf.set("hbase.regionserver.globalMemcache.upperLimit", "0.3");
    conf.set("hbase.regionserver.globalMemcache.lowerLimit", "0.15");

    Job job = new Job(conf);
    job.setJarByClass(BulkLoadMapReduce.class);
    job.setJobName(NAME);
    TextInputFormat.setInputPaths(job, new Path(args[0]));
    job.setInputFormatClass(TextInputFormat.class);
    job.setMapperClass(CustomMap.class);
    job.setOutputKeyClass(ImmutableBytesWritable.class);
    job.setOutputValueClass(Put.class);
    job.setNumReduceTasks(0);
    job.setOutputFormatClass(TableOutputFormat.class);

    job.waitForCompletion(true);
    return 0;
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Long startTime = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis();
    System.out.println("Start time : " + startTime);

    int errCode = ToolRunner.run(HBaseConfiguration.create(), new BulkLoadMapReduce(), args);

    Long endTime = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis();
    System.out.println("End time : " + endTime);
    System.out.println("Duration milliseconds: " + (endTime-startTime));

    System.exit(errCode);
}
```

Comment: I'm assuming you wanted your title to be "bulk load" and not "bluk load"...  but let me know if my correction was wrong.  :-)

Comment: Have you read this? http://hbase.apache.org/docs/r0.89.20100621/bulk-loads.html

Comment: Also, have you pre-split your regions?  If not, you basically have a single-threaded writer, which would explain it.  You basically get one writer per region.

Comment: Thanks for the typo correction Michael, i actually proof read my question twice... well, so much for stackoverflowing at 2 a.m..

Comment: @Chris: Yes, I've read that link earlier. About pre-splitting my regions: I didn't really understand that concept :(. Care to explain or how to do it?

Comment: Each row is in exactly one region, determined by it's row key. You can see which key ranges each region has in the web UI. If you don't pre-split regions, the data that you insert will all go into the first region until you reach the threshold for splitting that region, at which point it will be split evenly at whatever key happens to be the median of the keys in the region. If you don't pre-split your regions, all of your puts are going to be going into one region (on one node), until the split happens, and then only to two regions, etc. By pre-splitting you parallize writes from the start.

Comment: Pre-splitting is more of an art than a science. You need to find good key ranges that make sense for your data. To perform the pre-split, you can use the RegionSplitter class described here: http://hbase.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/util/RegionSplitter.html.  You launch this from the command line as an argument to the hbase shell command, e.g. "hbase org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.RegionSplitter"

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I've gone through a process that is probably very similar to yours of attempting to find an efficient way to load data from an MR into HBase. What I found to work is using `HFileOutputFormat` as the OutputFormatClass of the MR.

Below is the basis of my code that I have to generate the `job` and the Mapper `map` function which writes out the data. This was fast. We don't use it anymore, so I don't have numbers on hand, but it was around 2.5 million records in under a minute.

Here is the (stripped down) function I wrote to generate the job for my MapReduce process to put data into HBase

```
private Job createCubeJob(...) {
    //Build and Configure Job
    Job job = new Job(conf);
    job.setJobName(jobName);
    job.setMapOutputKeyClass(ImmutableBytesWritable.class);
    job.setMapOutputValueClass(Put.class);
    job.setMapperClass(HiveToHBaseMapper.class);//Custom Mapper
    job.setJarByClass(CubeBuilderDriver.class);
    job.setInputFormatClass(TextInputFormat.class);
    job.setOutputFormatClass(HFileOutputFormat.class);

    TextInputFormat.setInputPaths(job, hiveOutputDir);
    HFileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, cubeOutputPath);

    Configuration hConf = HBaseConfiguration.create(conf);
    hConf.set("hbase.zookeeper.quorum", hbaseZookeeperQuorum);
    hConf.set("hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort", hbaseZookeeperClientPort);

    HTable hTable = new HTable(hConf, tableName);

    HFileOutputFormat.configureIncrementalLoad(job, hTable);
    return job;
}
```

This is my map function from the `HiveToHBaseMapper` class (slightly edited ).

```
public void map(WritableComparable key, Writable val, Context context)
        throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    try{
        Configuration config = context.getConfiguration();
        String[] strs = val.toString().split(Constants.HIVE_RECORD_COLUMN_SEPARATOR);
        String family = config.get(Constants.CUBEBUILDER_CONFIGURATION_FAMILY);
        String column = strs[COLUMN_INDEX];
        String Value = strs[VALUE_INDEX];
        String sKey = generateKey(strs, config);
        byte[] bKey = Bytes.toBytes(sKey);
        Put put = new Put(bKey);
        put.add(Bytes.toBytes(family), Bytes.toBytes(column), (value <= 0) 
                        ? Bytes.toBytes(Double.MIN_VALUE)
                        : Bytes.toBytes(value));

        ImmutableBytesWritable ibKey = new ImmutableBytesWritable(bKey);
        context.write(ibKey, put);

        context.getCounter(CubeBuilderContextCounters.CompletedMapExecutions).increment(1);
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        context.getCounter(CubeBuilderContextCounters.FailedMapExecutions).increment(1);    
    }

}
```

I pretty sure this isn't going to be a Copy&Paste solution for you. Obviously the data I was working with here didn't need any custom processing (that was done in a MR job before this one). The main thing I want to provide out of this is the **`HFileOutputFormat`**. The rest is just an example of how I used it. :)
I hope it gets you onto a solid path to a good solution. :

Comment: I tried using `HfileOutputFormat` in my code but, i keep getting below exception, any ideas? 

`java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Put cannot be cast to org.apache.hadoop.hbase.KeyValue
 at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.HFileOutputFormat$1.write(HFileOutputFormat.java:82)
 at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask$NewTrackingRecordWriter.write(ReduceTask.java:508)
 at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.TaskInputOutputContext.write(TaskInputOutputContext.java:80)
 at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer.reduce(Reducer.java:156)
 ...`

Comment: @kramer More than, attempting to `write` a a different type than it is expecting (hence the cast error) not really. Would need to see the code to take a shot at that.

Comment: Is HFileOutputFormat faster then TableOutputFormat? Given equal situation with region splitting.

Comment: Which jar has this `HfileOutputFormat`class? I can't find it

Answer (score 0):

> One interesting thing is that during insertion of 1,000,000 rows, 25 Mappers (tasks) are spawned but they run serially (one after another); is this normal?

`mapreduce.tasktracker.map.tasks.maximum` parameter which is defaulted to 2 determines the maximum number of tasks that can run in parallel on a node. Unless changed, you should see 2 map tasks running simultaneously on each node.

Comment: Tried that but the result didn't change.

Comment: Where did you specify the parameter? It should be specified in the mapred-site.xml on all the nodes before the Hadoop daemons start. Check this [documentation](http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/FAQ#I_see_a_maximum_of_2_maps.2BAC8-reduces_spawned_concurrently_on_each_TaskTracker.2C_how_do_I_increase_that.3F). How did you verify? Can be verified from the JobTracker Web Console.