# Loading CSV File into Hbase table using MapReduce

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, hbase

I need to load data of csv file into hbase table. I have the csv file in the above format

Csv file: Read Detachcard.csv

```
year  class    days   mm   
   1964   9     20.5     8.8          
   1964  10     13.6     4.2      
   1964  11     11.8     4.7     
   1964  12      7.7     0.1       
   1965   1      7.3     0.8       
   1965   2     6.5     0.1         
   1965   3     10.8     1.4         
   1965   4     13.2     3.5         
   1965   5     16.1     7.0         
   1965   6     19.0     9.2          
   1965   7     18.7    10.7       
   1965   8     19.9    10.9          
   1965   9      16.6     8.2
```

In the above file, the top first row is column qualifier names and from 2nd row is the values for column qualifier. now i need to load this data into hbase table using mapreducing program. How to read this data into put command and row autoincrement? I have no idea of this kind of format. please can any one guide me or show me some samples to load this kind of data into hbase table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use csvreader , it is quite easy to operate on csv files with this jar.
find csvreader jar and place it in jre.

```
CsvReader products = new CsvReader("CSV file path ");

        products.readHeaders();

        while (products.readRecord())
        {
            String productID = products.get("year");
            String productName = products.get("class");
            String supplierID = products.get("day");
            String categoryID = products.get("mm");

        }

        products.close();
```

Comment: Hi, i need to use MapReduce only which doesnt have CSVREADER, i have updated my post with my class please check

Answer (score 2):

I think your data is 'tab : \t' separated.
What you can do is, read/parse each line in your mapper and create a put object
then pass it to hbase.

check this link : 
[What is the fastest way to bulk load data into HBase programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8750764/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-bulk-load-data-into-hbase-programmatically/8751176#8751176)

Comment: Please check, i have updated my question. i need to read data from that file , i am not sure how to read data into put method and add data