# reading data from hdfs and storing it to hbase?

Tags: hadoop, hbase

I have data in form:

```
source, destination, connection
```

This data is saved in hdfs

I want to read this data and put it in hbase table something like:

```
       Column1 (source) |    Column2(Destination)     | Column3(Connection Type)

Row    vertex A         |        vertex B             | connection
```

How do I do this?
Thanks

Comment: Is it comma separated in HDFS

Comment: @Anand: seperated by space

Comment: what would you want for the row keys?

Comment: @ArnonRotem-Gal-Oz Column 1.. will work as key .. bt the issue is that while each row is unique but each column can have multiple same values. example

A 1 foo;
A 2 foo;
A, 2 foo

Comment: You need a unique key -otherwise another record with the same vertex A would override an existing record

Answer (score 0):

Refer [Loading csv data into Hbase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13906847/loading-csv-data-into-hbase).
They use comma seperated value, but you can change it to use space