# MySQL and HBase Optimized data storage (1 TB)

Tags: mysql, sql, csv, amazon-ec2, hbase

I have approximately 600 million rows of data is 157 CSV files. The data is in the following format:

```
A: 8 digit int
B: 64bit unsigned int
C: 140 characters long string
D: int
```

I will use the CSV to load data into a MySQL and HBase database. I am deciding on how to optimize the process of loading? I need help with the following queries:

1. Use a single table to store all data or Shard it into multiple tables
2. What Optimizations can I do to reduce load time?
3. Improve overall performance of the database? Should normalize the table to store the information?

I will be using an M1.Large EC2 instance each to load the CSV into MySQL and HBase database.

> ============UPDATE============ 
>   I used a C3.8XLarge instance and it took 2 hours to load 20 CSV files (157 total) of 250Mb each. Eventually I
>   had to stop it as it was taking too long. The CPU utilization was only
>   2% throughout the entire time period. If anyone can help, then please
>   do!

Answer (score 0):

For HBase, you can use the standard [CSV Bulk Load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13906847/loading-csv-data-into-hbase)
For MySQL, you will have to use regular [CSV MySQL Load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14127529/mysql-import-data-from-csv-using-load-data-infile)

And Normalizing the data is upto you.
Looking at your data structure, I think you probably don't need normalization.

Comment: It works only if you have small dataset. The approach is not scalable.