# Determine exactly files from HDFS to load into one Hbase table using java?

Tags: java, hadoop, hbase

I'm new at Big Data and Hadoop. I'm learning Hadoop and Hbase. I got a problem but still had no idea. Could you help me?

I've put 3 csv files to HDFS, include:
- File 1(Subscribe_info.txt): numID, active_date, status
- File 2(Recharge.txt): numID, recharge_history_date, amount, method
- File 3 (Charge.txt): numID, charge_date, amount_charge

All of them related with each other by: numID.

I need to load all data above into a Hbase table with row key is the numID and contain all columns related, like this:

```
Hbase table: rowkey= userID -- Column: active_date - status - recharge_history - amount_recharge - method - charge - history - amount
```

I use Java and I've created 3 classes to parse the data from 3 data files. But I don't know how I can read the file path from HDFS and parse to put it into the Hbase table.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Loading csv data into Hbase](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13906847/loading-csv-data-into-hbase)

Comment: There are three different questions: how to read (and write) HDFS files? how to merge data from three files? how to import data into HBase? All three can be easily solved by following various tutorials.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your requirement has these steps

1) You have to read the HDFS file (in your case you have to read csv file you can use [Open CSV](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/) just I have given an example below to read a normal file)

2) prepare a put and upload in to HBASE

I have already mentioned the code to do it [here. pls have a look](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38633419/solutions-to-put-different-values-for-a-row-key-but-the-same-timestamps-in-hbase/38652815#38652815)

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.net.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.util.*;


public class Cat{
        public static void main (String [] args) throws Exception{
                try{
                        Path pt=new Path("hdfs://npvm11.np.wc1.yellowpages.com:9000/user/john/abc.txt");
                        FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(new Configuration());
                        BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fs.open(pt)));
                        String line;
                        line=br.readLine();
                        while (line != null){
                                System.out.println(line);
                                line=br.readLine();
                        }
                }catch(Exception e){
                }
        }
}
```

Hope this helps..

Comment: if you are okay with above answer, pls. flag-up as "accepted by owner"