# Dynamic dataframe with n columns and m rows

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Reading data from `json`(dynamic schema) and i'm loading that to dataframe.

Example Dataframe:

```
scala> import spark.implicits._
import spark.implicits._

scala> val DF = Seq(
     (1, "ABC"),
     (2, "DEF"),
     (3, "GHIJ")
     ).toDF("id", "word")
someDF: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [number: int, word: string]

scala> DF.show
+------+-----+
|id    | word|
+------+-----+
|     1|  ABC|
|     2|  DEF|
|     3| GHIJ|
+------+-----+
```

Requirement:
Column count and names can be anything. I want to read rows in loop to fetch each column one by one. Need to process that value in subsequent flows. Need both column name and value. I'm using scala.

```
Python:
for i, j in df.iterrows(): 
    print(i, j)
```

Need the same functionality in scala and it column name and value should be fetched separtely.

Kindly help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`df.iterrows` is not from pyspark, but from pandas. In Spark, you can use `foreach` :

```
DF
  .foreach{_ match {case Row(id:Int,word:String) => println(id,word)}}
```

Result :

```
(2,DEF)
(3,GHIJ)
(1,ABC)
```

I you don't know the number of columns, you cannot use `unapply` on `Row`, then just do :

```
DF
  .foreach(row => println(row))
```

Result :

```
[1,ABC]
[2,DEF]
[3,GHIJ]
```

And operate with `row` using its methods `getAs` etc

Comment: Thanks Ram & Raphael. I'm trying to generate dynamic Put statement to load the streaming data into hbase. Any other best solution to consider apart from shc connector?

Comment: see [my answer writeHbase](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56297890/647053) may be you need to tailor according to your needs since you have dynamic columns

Comment: How i can get dynamic column name inside "getAs"? Thanks