# Bulk Inserts in HBase from a file

Tags: sql, database, hadoop, hbase

I am trying to insert a lot of rows into a table (my target is to insert a billion dummy rows). This is what I did:

1. I wrote the billion SQL lines corresponding to the inserts into a file.
2. `./hbase shell < insert.sql`

First few inserts go through fine, but very soon I keep on running into this error

```
put 'test', 'row19115', 'cf:a', '19115'

ERROR: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create new native thread

Here is some help for this command:
Put a cell 'value' at specified table/row/column and optionally
timestamp coordinates.  To put a cell value into table 't1' at
row 'r1' under column 'c1' marked with the time 'ts1', do:

  hbase> put 't1', 'r1', 'c1', 'value', ts1
```

- **How to fix this error / Is there a better way to do it?**
- **Also, is there some other way to do the inserts rather than writing them to a file everytime?**

Comment: Another option is to prepare your data in a `HFile` format and then efficiently bulk insert into HBase. See: http://hbase.apache.org/book.html#arch.bulk.load . Also see section `12.9.2.4` at http://hbase.apache.org/book/trouble.rs.html whether it helps.

Comment: You may want to have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8750764/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-bulk-load-data-into-hbase-programmatically